# Installing ubuntu on usb and booting on uefi

Tags: uefi, usb-drive

I have a new Laptop with Windows 8 preinstalled. I want to install Ubuntu on a USB stick. Then I want to boot form the USB and use Ubuntu when I need. When I don't need Ubuntu I just want to boot Win 8 from the HD. I don't want to partition my Windows drive. Is this possible? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent) is all the info you need. Scroll down until you get to *Installing Ubuntu on USB drive using Windows*.

Comment: That page doesn't mention EFI at all, and there may be some EFI-specific quirks that will need addressing. I haven't tested the procedure, though, so I'm not positive what (if anything) will need changing.

Comment: There is no *quirks* for Ubuntu. I wasn't able to boot others distributions (for example debian, slackware) with the UEFI's Secure Boot enabled, but with Ubuntu (12.04) everything was fine.

Since you want to install it just on a USB-Stick, you can try it out. You will lose only about 1 hour and nothing more.